# What is this "string" in front of canopy of F-14

Tags: aircraft-systems

I was just watching scenes from Final Countdown movie and this little stringy bit caught my attention. Anyone knows what it is and what is its purpose?

[Here is the video I saw it in.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SwgU42XSpw)

[image]

Comment: I saw this but not sure if it is the same thing.

Comment: In case somebody doesn't want to search the video for it, the above screenshot is from ~4:14 in the referenced video.

Comment: [Yaw string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaw_string), also see [Yaw String Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=f-14+yaw+string&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1683&bih=927&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB1NGfxMPLAhWEmIMKHVo0Ae8QsAQIGw) and the U-2 has one, along with the AF-9J and AV8.

Comment: Ok, cheers, seems like it can be closed as a duplicate then. Thank you